# Reformat number in specific column

Tags: awk, numeric-data

I have semicolon delimited data, where third column is decimal number:

```
A;B;1234.56
C;D;789.23
```

I need to make 2 changes to the format of the number:

1. remove numbers after the decimal point
2. add "thousand separator" to the number

so `1234.56` would become `1'234`

I was able to do the first part, but don't know how to add the thousand separator:

```
printf "A;B;1234.56\nC;D;789.23\n" | awk -F';' '{gsub(/\.../,"",$3) ; printf "%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3 }'
```

how can I do that ?

Comment: Also relevant: [How do I format number locale-specific in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801401/how-do-i-format-number-locale-specific-in-perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `LC_NUMERIC='en_US.UTF-8'` locale (that has supporting the comma as the thousands separator formatting for the numbers) and using the `sprintf`'s `%\047d` (`%\047d` is just another type of writing single quote `%'d` using the [Octal Escape Sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html), or you can write it `%'\''d` too) format modifier to force convert the floating point numbers into integers plus use the *comma* as the thousands separator and then we used the `gsub()` function to convert the commas to single quotes.

```
$ LC_NUMERIC='en_US.UTF-8' awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=";" }
  { $3=sprintf ("%\047d", $3); gsub(",", "\047", $3) }1' infile
A;B;1'234
C;D;789
```